# HAProxy and SSL Certification

Tags: ssl, haproxy

So I want to do SSL certification on HAProxy to make the connection secure. I started of downloading HAProxy through appstore but later found out that the installation package doesnt support SSL. So I downloaded HAProxy 1.5.14 and compiled it with USE_OPENSSL=1. when I do haproxy -vv I am able to see that SSL is enabled in it.

The issue that I am facing is that when I compile and then install the file by using the command (sudo make install), I am unable to find the haproxy.cfg. I dont know where it is so I am unable to configure and set the setting to the requirement.

The installation package that I got is from the HAProxy official site and I would like someone's help. Please advice me how to solve this issue.

Thank you, 
Safiul Hasan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no default haproxy.cfg file, you have to create it from scratch.
Look for some samples on the internet to get one fitting your needs.
You can put your configuration file anywhere and ask to haproxy to use it by using the "-f" parameter.

Comment: How will I use the "-f" parameter? Can you give me an example. please & thank you

Answer (score 1):

The default config file location is:
/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

You can also search your system for the file with this command:
find / -name 'haproxy.cfg'

If haproxy is already running successfully you can find out what config file it is using by looking at the command that is used to run it:
ps x | grep haproxy

This will result in output like this:
28548 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg

The part after the "-f" is the path to the config file haproxy is currently using.